# "No Chart Data Available" MPAndroidChart in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I've been trying to make a linechart with the MPAndroidChart library from Github following an old tutorial, so I don't use the newest version (3.1.0) but rather I have to use an older one (2.2.4) as the coding has changed since then and I don't know how to create a linechart according to the newest version.

Problem is, I've been trying everything to get the code working, and don't get me wrong, the code "Works", and the build is done correctly, so I'm able to test it on my physical device, but for some reason, after opening the APK to see the result, it tells me that "No chart data alvailable". I think the problem is related to the LineChart inside the RelativeLayout that is in the activity_main.xml. I've tried findViewByID and View Binding but I always get the same result.

Could you guys tell me the reason of why I'm wrong? or maybe teach me how to make linecharts based according to the newest verion. Help is appreciated.

MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.actualgraphtesting

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.actualgraphtesting.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity (){

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    fun setLineChartData()
    {
        val xvalue = ArrayList<String>()
        xvalue.add("13")
        xvalue.add("6")
        xvalue.add("17")
        xvalue.add("5")
        xvalue.add("8")

        val lineentry = ArrayList<Entry>();
        lineentry.add(Entry(20f , 0))
        lineentry.add(Entry(50f , 1))
        lineentry.add(Entry(70f , 2))
        lineentry.add(Entry(10f , 3))
        lineentry.add(Entry(30f , 4))

        val linedataset = LineDataSet(lineentry, "First")
        linedataset.color = resources.getColor(R.color.purple_500)

        val data = LineData(xvalue, linedataset)

        binding.lineChart.data = data
        binding.lineChart.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
        binding.lineChart.animateXY(3000, 3000)



    }



}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lineChart"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to actually call your function setLineChartData() in onCreate